# Treating an inherently multiclass problem as a two-class problem

Tags: classification, multi-class

I'm not an expert in this area, so if this question sounds a bit ill-informed, it is!

I'm working on a problem somewhat akin to classifying birds with image data as input. Let's say for training data, I have images of Robins, Cardinals, Woodpeckers and Finches. Let's also say that for test data, I only want to know if a given image is a Cardinal, or not a Cardinal.

What are the pros and cons of treating this as a two-class (one class?) problem vs solving this as a multiclass problem?

I've tried working with sklearn classifiers (mostly LogisticRegression and SVC), and I seem to get better results when I solve the problem as a multiclass problem. That is, using all four labels (Robins, Cardinals, ...) in the training set, and then applying "Cardinal or not" at the "presentation" level. However, another factor is that my data set is not all that huge, and this results in some of the labels having relatively low counts.

The two-class approach would seem to mitigate the low-data issue (assuming there's enough data for Cardinals), and there's also an intuitive sense that this view of the problem is somewhat simpler, though I suppose that may be subjective. However, working with LogisticRegression and SVC, I tend to get worse results than I do going the multiclass route.

Any guidance on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: is it better according to AUC metric?

Comment: Yes, better according to ROC AUC, and also average PR.

Comment: it's weird since multiclass problems are in sklearn usually implemented as a collection of binary one versus one or one versus all classifiers, so similar to what you are trying to do manually. In this sense, there shouldn't really be any pros and cons, since it should be the same thing